# "Invalid info.plist value" when uploading iOS 9 app extension

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, xcode7, ios9, osx-elcapitan

I'm trying to upload an iOS 9 beta app with three app extensions to Testflight, but each time I try to upload a build I get three errors each containing basically the same text:

> ERROR ITMS-90362: "Invalid Info.plist value. The value for the key 'NSExtensionPointIdentifier' in bundle [App Name].app/PlugIns/[Extension Name].appex is invalid."

But for some reason with one of the extensions (an Action Extension) the `NSExtensionPointIdentifier` is replaced with `NSExtensionActivationRule`. I tried creating a new extension to test if it was specifically for these few, but it generated the same error again for the new one.

I have looked everywhere, but Google wasn't any help either.

I'm currently running OS X El Capitan Beta and Xcode 7.0 beta 7A120f. The app runs just fine in the Simulator.

Comment: You can't load beta code to itunes connect or anything that is compiled with beta xcode software. Simple as that.

Comment: How else do you upload it to testflight..? They clearly stated at the WWDC that they will allow iOS 9 beta apps on TF

Comment: I didn't catch that at WWDC. I was just stating this from previous experience trying to upload beta compiled code for iOS 8.